# Unable to post a value selected from db in a drop down box

Tags: php, post, get, echo

I had spent some time trying to get the drop down box working correctly, getting the values of department and location to populate from the DB. This is working fine and I have added additionally date fields so a customer can select records for a specific period, location and department. When I action the form running departmentReport.php the page returns blank even when trying to echo each value as seen below.

```
   <form id="departmentReport" action="departmentReport.php" method="get" onsubmit="#">
        <fieldset id="departmentReport">
          <h3>Department Report</h3>
            <br>
          <?php
          include 'includes/DbCon.php';
        $sql = "select department_name from departments";

          echo"<select name = 'departments' value=''>Department Name</option>";

          foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row){
              echo "<option value=$row[department_name]>$row[department_name]</option>";}
          echo "</select>";

          ?>
          <br></br>
    <?php
          include 'includes/DbCon.php';
        $sql = "select `location_name` from `location`";

          echo  "<select name = 'location' value=''>Location Name</option>";

          foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row){
              echo "<option value=$row[location_name]>$row[location_name]</option>";}
          echo "</select>";

          ?>
            <br></br><br>
                <label for="date">Date From<br></label>
                <input id="date1" type="date" name="dateF"
                       autofocus="true"/>
            <br>
            <br>
                <label for="date">Date To<br></label>
                <input id="date2" type="date" name="date2"
                       autofocus="true"/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
```

On Submit departmentReport.php is actioned

```
<?php


include "../includes/dbCon.php";  //* CONNECTION TO DATABASE

$department = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['departments']);  //* CLEAN DATA, THIS DELETES ANY SPECIAL CHARACTERS THAT CAN BE USED FOR MALICIOUS CODE 
$location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['location']);   //* CLEAN DATA, THIS DELETES ANY SPECIAL CHARACTERS THAT CAN BE USED FOR MALICIOUS CODE 
$date1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date1']); //* CLEAN DATA, THIS DELETES ANY SPECIAL CHARACTERS THAT CAN BE USED FOR MALICIOUS CODE 
$date2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date2']); //* CLEAN DATA, THIS DELETES ANY SPECIAL CHARACTERS THAT CAN BE USED FOR MALICIOUS CODE 

echo "$department";  
echo "$location";
echo "$date1";
echo "$date2";
```

This brings the results below..

[image: department report form]

[image: result on submit]

However when adjusting post to get I see the values I selected
http://localhost:8888/departmentReport.php?departments=Marketing&location=London&dateFrom=02%2F01%2F2017

Im unsure why I cannot see the values when echoing them!

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable when retrieving the post data is wrong

Select department html code:

```
<select name = departments value=''>Department Name</option>
```

In the select form, the name is "departments", but when you retrieve them in the PHP, it is:

```
$_POST['departmant_name']
```

Which is wrong input variable name. It should be:

```
$_POST['departments']
```

Also, please put quotes mark on the select name

```
<select name = 'departments' value=''>Department Name</option>
```

All other variable also wrong.

Looks like you entered the database column name, not the form input name.

Edit:
I also noticed that in your form, the form "method" is set to "GET" while your PHP code is using "POST"

Comment: I don't think this is the case I have made the amendments however when I click submit the following page goes blank. I can however put echo "test"; and the result is as expected. As soon as I echo "$location"; for example the page is blank.

Comment: That is weird. Does normal form submit works? Try making as simple form, with maybe 1 or 2 input textbox, and try to submit that and display it value.

Also, you could try to just use $_POST[] without the mysqli_real_escape_string(), see if the it work

Comment: Il have a play now thanks afif it seems the issue is I'm selecting values from the db for the drop down box. When I'm trying to submit the selected value onwards its not sending any value.

Comment: `<select name="department" <option value="1">Marketing</option>      <option value='3'>R&D</option><option value='2'>IT Helpdesk</option>   <option value='4'>Administrative</option></select>.                                          This would work fine however we will be adding new departments all the time it needs to fetch the results from the db ensuring minimal changes are required in code.